# Is it possible to add a list of contacts to an iOS/iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Could I add a text file containing a list of my friends' phone numbers to my contacts without doing it manually/individually?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Text/email yourself a VCF file containing the contacts, tap the VCF file, you will be prompted to add them to your default contacts list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shortcut for this that performs the following steps:

1. Text action, or other method of getting text into the shortcut.
2. Repeat with each across the text, so Repeat Item becomes each item in the list.
3. Use the Add Contact action to add a new contact, using Repeat Item as the source of information.

If your list of phone numbers also contains their name and some delimiter, you'll need to add an action between actions 2 and 3 to split the text by the delimiter so you have access to the components of each line.